# Function that changes number in string to int

Tags: c, string, function, if-statement, int

I'm trying to code a function in c that changes a number in string to an integer. For example "one" to 1. This is my code so far but it is not working how its supposed to and I can't find the problem.

Comment: Can you provide details on what "not working how its supposed to" means?

Comment: `strcmp` is case sensitive.  Are you sure the case of all characters match?

Comment: There is no reason for `num` to be a function parameter. It should just be a local variable.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Its not working how its supposed to because its not returning the correct value of num. So for example value might be "Seven" and num will be returned as 1 which is why I'm guessing there's a problem with the if statement.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example of `main()` showing how you call this.

Comment: So I'm calling this from another function not main but I'm going to add that code.

Comment: @m.18, You are passing an integer to the function when calling and printing that value. You should capture the return value here. If you want to pass the integer `lastval`, pass it as pointer. Otherwise changes done in function will be lost

Comment: @kuro Ok I'll try that. However, I am new at using pointers

Comment: @m.18, no, You are passing `lastval` as value not pointer. Either remove integer function parameter completely and capture the return value. Or, pass a pointer and make the function void. Better to stick to the first one

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the return value of the function when you call it:

```
toint(array[i-1], lastval);
```

Also, parameters in C are pass by value, meaning that changes to a parameter in a function aren't reflected in the calling function, so there's no need to pass in `lastvar`.

Change the function to get rid of the second parameter:

```
int toint(char value[10]){
    int num = 0;
    ...
```

Add assign the return value to `lastval`:

```
lastval = toint(array[i-1]);
```

Comment: This solution worked. It's still not exactly how I want it but I think it's a problem with rand() this time.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
char *numbers[] = {
    "Zero", "One", "Two" ,"Three", "Four", "Five",
    "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"
};

int tonum( char *str ) {
    for( int i=0; i<11; i++) {
        if( !strcmpi( str, numbers[i]) ) return i;
    }
    return -1;  // not found
}
```

and then you call it like this:

```
print( "%s is %d\n", "Seven", tonum("seven") );
```

`strcmpi()` takes care about uppercase/lowercase stuff.